# Redis/ Spring Cache --> Want to read http response and json response before I cache

Tags: caching, redis, spring-cache, redisson

I am using Redis cache for API response caching. I want to store data to the cache only if the HTTP response status code is 200. If the HTTP response status code is 500, then I do not want to cache the data. And, also if my response has certain data which I want to read and then decide if I want to cache (my response data is always json response). Can I do it? How do I achieve this?

I am trying something like this:

```java
@Cacheable(value = "EmployeeInfo", key = "#emp_name")
public EmployeeInformation getEmplInfo(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, String emp_name) {
    return serviceImpl.getEmployeeInfor(emp_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is generally possible and supported by the *Spring Cache Abstraction's*, [Conditional Caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition) feature.

Based on your short code snippet above, it would look similar to the following:

```java
@Cacheable(value = "EmployeeInfo", key = "#emp_name", 
  unless = "#response.status != 200")
public EmployeeInformation getEmplInfo(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, String emp_name) { 

    // ...
}
```

In this case, you would use the `@Cacheable` annotation's `unless` attribute since the `getEmplInfo(..)` method's result (and logic) would be needed to determine and set the appropriate HTTP status code of the `HttpServletResponse` object passed into the method.

Given the JSON returned by the `@Cacheable`, `getEmplInfo(..)` method is supposedly converted and represented by an `EmployeeInformation` type, and additionally, given the `@Cacheable` annotation's condition-based attributes, such as `condition` and `unless`, accept SpEL expressions, then you could compose the necessary SpEL expressions using [logical operators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-operators-logical).

For example:

```java
unless = "#response.status != 200 && !#result.fullTime"
```

In this configuration, it assumes the employee, represented by your `EmployeeInformation` type, has a boolean property called `fullTime`.

The `unless` condition effectively says only cache the `EmployeeInformation` by the `emp_name` key if the HTTP status code set in the method is 200 (SUCCESS) **AND** the person is a full-time employee.

It isn't too difficult to further imagine more complex configurations and SpEL expressions made possible by the [SpEL language](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-language-ref), itself.

Of course, if you need some seriously low-level, really complex conditional logic, beyond what is possible with SpEL, then you would need to decorate the caching provider implementation (i.e. Redis in your case) using [Spring's Cache API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/package-summary.html).

Every single *caching provider implementation* supplied by Spring is represented by 2 interfaces in the *Cache Abstraction*: [`Cache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) and [`CacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html), no exceptions.

Since `Cache` and `CacheManager` are interfaces, you can either supply your own implementations, or alternatively (and recommended), you can create "Wrappers" around an existing cache provider's (e.g. Redis's) implementation to enhance (i.e. "decorate") the existing caching behavior with additional (perhaps, conditional logic).  Make sense?

The later is a rather advanced topic and something I have demonstrated in past SO `spring-cache` posts before for other users' Use Cases.  You can usually get pretty far with just SpEL by itself, so let's start there and if you need more assistance I am happy to share working examples in the comments.  Just let me know.

I hope this helps kick start some ideas for you.

Cheers!